# What does DoCmd.FindRecord reveal and how to get it?

Tags: vba, ms-access

What does `DoCmd.FindRecord` actually do? Does it have an output or value, and how do I see it?

I am in Access VBA and trying to find a specific table record based upon an individual name.
Why have FindRecord if it does not yield a Yes/No or True/False?

I am using a form to allow/input an employee's details in a shift schedule.

```
X = "Jim3"
DoCmd.FindRecord "X", , False, , True
```

Answer (score 0):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.docmd.findrecord

> When a procedure calls the FindRecord method, **Access searches for the specified data in the records** (the order of the search is determined by the setting of the Search argument). When Access finds the specified data, **the data is selected in the record**.
>
> **The FindRecord method does not return a value indicating its success or failure**. To determine whether a value exists in a recordset, use the **FindFirst**, FindNext, FindPrevious, or FindLast method of the Recordset object. These methods set the value of the NoMatch property to True if the specified value is not found.

Note that you'd have to use `DoCmd.FindRecord X` (not `"X"`) to find anything.